Can mount with command but can't set up udev rule
I've bought an SSD and I want to use it as storage on my RaspberryPi. It's formatted and when connected to the pi I can see it with:
> lsusb

Bus 001 Device 004: ID 152d:a580 JMicron Technology Corp. / JMicron USA Technology Corp. USB Mass Storage
# ... other stuff here

lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk
├─sda1        8:1    0    16M  0 part
└─sda2        8:2    0   1.8T  0 part 
mmcblk0     179:0    0 117.8G  0 disk
├─mmcblk0p1 179:1    0   256M  0 part /boot
└─mmcblk0p2 179:2    0 117.5G  0 part /

So I mount the drive:
sudo mount -o uid=leonardo,gid=leonardo,umask=000 /dev/sda2 /shared/usb

Check that it's correctly mounted:
lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk
├─sda1        8:1    0    16M  0 part
└─sda2        8:2    0   1.8T  0 part /shared/usb
mmcblk0     179:0    0 117.8G  0 disk
├─mmcblk0p1 179:1    0   256M  0 part /boot
└─mmcblk0p2 179:2    0 117.5G  0 part /

Everything works perfectly!
So I now want this to happen automatically. After some googling I land on setting up a udev rule:
sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/99-usb-mount.rules

Inside the file:
KERNEL=="sda2", SUBSYSTEMS=="block", ATTRS{idVendor}=="152d", ATTRS{idProduct}=="a580", ACTION=="add", RUN+="/bin/su leonardo -c '-o uid=leonardo,gid=leonardo,umask=000 /dev/sda2 /shared/usb'"

Then I reload rules:
sudo udevadm control --reload-rules

But nothing. It doesn't auto mount even I unplug it and replug it.
Why? What am I doing wrong?

Can you explain why you're using udev for this instead of just putting the drive in /etc/fstab?
